# Combining columns based on group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
         POLY_KEY_I     SP1     SP2
0   FS01080100SM001  POAPRA  TOXRYD
1   FS01080100SM001     NaN     NaN
2   FS01080100SM001   OXRYD  SYMOCC
3   FS01080100SM001  EUPESU  POAPRA
4   FS01080100SM001  BOUGRA  KOEPYR
5   FS01080100SM002  POAPRA  EUPESU
6   FS01080100SM002  POAPRA     NaN
7   FS01080100SM002  POAPRA  KOEPYR
```

And I want to groupby `POLY_KEY_I` and then combine `SP1` and `SP2` based on this.

My desired output would be something like:

```
         POLY_KEY_I      SP
0   FS01080100SM001  POAPRA
1   FS01080100SM001  TOXRYD
2   FS01080100SM001     NaN
3   FS01080100SM001     NaN
4   FS01080100SM001   OXRYD
5   FS01080100SM001  SYMOCC
6   FS01080100SM001  EUPESU
7   FS01080100SM001  POAPRA
8   FS01080100SM001  BOUGRA
9   FS01080100SM001  KOEPYR 
10  FS01080100SM002  POAPRA
11  FS01080100SM002  EUPESU
12  FS01080100SM002  POAPRA
13  FS01080100SM002     NaN
14  FS01080100SM002  POAPRA
15  FS01080100SM002  KOEPYR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-melt) to reshape from wide to long, like this:

```
In [10]: pd.melt(df, id_vars='POLY_KEY_I', value_name='SP')
Out[10]: 
         POLY_KEY_I variable      SP
0   FS01080100SM001      SP1  POAPRA
1   FS01080100SM001      SP1     NaN
2   FS01080100SM001      SP1   OXRYD
3   FS01080100SM001      SP1  EUPESU
4   FS01080100SM001      SP1  BOUGRA
5   FS01080100SM002      SP1  POAPRA
6   FS01080100SM002      SP1  POAPRA
7   FS01080100SM002      SP1  POAPRA
8   FS01080100SM001      SP2  TOXRYD
9   FS01080100SM001      SP2     NaN
10  FS01080100SM001      SP2  SYMOCC
11  FS01080100SM001      SP2  POAPRA
12  FS01080100SM001      SP2  KOEPYR
13  FS01080100SM002      SP2  EUPESU
14  FS01080100SM002      SP2     NaN
15  FS01080100SM002      SP2  KOEPYR
```

Comment: I would drop `variable` column

Comment: actually ill need that for a join later on